# Setup project visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

What can be the reason that install is greyed out?

Microsoft Istaller projects 2022 is installed. Solution can build without problems.

It's an old project where .net Framework 4.0 is used.

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but it might be that .NET Framework 4.0 is deprecated and support was removed. You can't even install it via the Visual Studio Installer's Individual Components. The lowest 4.x targeting pack version I could install is 4.6.

Try installing the latest .NET Framework targeting pack and then re-target the project to use that.